# I'm getting negative value for this function with modulus operator even though there is no subtraction, for very large numbers in Java and C

Tags: java, python, modulus

```
int invMod(int a) {
        int b=1;
        a=a%1000003;
        for (int i=0;i<1000001;i++) {
            b=(b*a)%1000003;
        }
        return b;
  }
```

When I use this function for 5700010 as input in Java and C I'm getting a negative answer -306812, whereas when I run the same code (different syntax, same logic) in Python I'm getting 183099 which is what I want.
Please help, I'm not able to get the logic for this. There is no reason for it to become negative. I guess the only reason it would get negative is because of overflow, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, you can expect those numbers to overflow.  Use a `long` for `b`.

Comment: but it shouldnt right? I'm using a using mod for that very reason. And how does it become negative?

Comment: Sure it should overflow.  You're multiplying `5700010 % 1000003 = 699995` by a number that could be as large as `1000002`.  That gives you a result of up to about 700 billion.  An `int` goes up to about 2 billion.  You need a `long`.  And because `int` values are stored in a way that gives a negative value to the most significant bit, it's entirely normal for an `int` (or a `long` for that matter) to turn negative when it overflows.